# multiple update images not showing in request all laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, dropzone.js

I'm doing multiple upload images using dropzone.js. The main reason is to enable the user can upload (drag and drop) multiple images.

For upload(store) images it works fine can upload properly but updating multiple images have problem when I dd request all there is no value [image: value]
returned for multiple images but only return value from request form. I have tried including paramName = file but still didn't get any request from file.

How to update multiple images and get the request value to store in table?

edit.blade.php

```
<script>
   let companyId = @json($companies);
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            (function() {
                var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#multipleFileUpload", {
                    url: '/admin/company/update/' + companyId,
                    method: 'POST',
                    paramName: 'file',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    acceptedFiles: ".jpg,.png,.jpeg",
                    maxFiles: 999,
                    maxFilesize: 2,
                    addRemoveLinks: true,
                    uploadMultiple: false,
                    autoProcessQueue: false,
                    parallelUploads: 999,
                    dictCancelUpload: "Cancel",
                    dictDefaultMessage: "Please drag & drop images here",
                    timeout: 5000,
                    init: function() {
                        dzClosure =
                            this; // Makes sure that 'this' is understood inside the functions below.

                        // for Dropzone to process the queue (instead of default form behavior):
                        document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener(
                            "click",
                            function(e) {
                                // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
                                e.preventDefault();
                                e.stopPropagation();
                                dzClosure.processQueue();
                            });

                        // send all the form data along with the files:
                        this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
                            formData.append("name", jQuery("#name")
                                .val());
                            formData.append("email", jQuery("#email")
                                .val());

                            formData.append("dropzone", jQuery(
                                    "#multipleFileUpload")
                                .val());

                            formData.append("file", document.getElementById(
                                'multipleFileUpload'));

                            formData.append("logo", document.getElementById(
                                'companyLogo').files[0]);

                            formData.append("phone_number", jQuery(
                                    "#phoneNumber")
                                .val());

                            formData.append("fax_number", jQuery("#faxNumber")
                                .val());

                            formData.append("address1", jQuery("#address1")
                                .val());

                            formData.append("address2", jQuery("#address2")
                                .val());

                            formData.append("city", jQuery("#city")
                                .val());

                            formData.append("postcode", jQuery("#postcode")
                                .val());

                            formData.append("state", jQuery("#state")
                                .val());

                            formData.append("country", jQuery("#country")
                                .val());

                            formData.append("longitude", jQuery("#longitude")
                                .val());

                            formData.append("latitude", jQuery("#latitude")
                                .val());
                        });
                    },
                    success: function(file, response) {
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Success!',
                            text: 'Image added successfully',
                            confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
                        }).then(function() {
                            window.location.href =
                                "{{ route('admin.company.index') }}"
                        });
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        return false
                    },
                    init: function() {
                        var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit");
                        myDropzone = this;
                        submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
                            myDropzone.processQueue();
                        });

                        this.on('complete', function() {
                            if (this.getQueuedFiles().length == 0 && this
                                .getUploadingFiles()
                                .length == 0) {
                                var _this = this;
                                _this.removeAllFiles();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            })();
        });
    });

</script>


<div class="col-12 form-group">
                                            <div class="card">
                                                <div class="card-header">Image Upload</div>
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <div class="dropzone" id="multipleFileUpload" name="dropzone">
                                                        @foreach ($companies->images as $image)
                                                            <div class="img-wrap">
                                                                <a href="#" onclick="deleteImage({{ $image->id }})"
                                                                    class="close btn-delete btn-image-delete"
                                                                    id="btn-delete"
                                                                    data-image-id={{ $image->id }}>&times;</a>
                                                                <img class="image-dropzone"
                                                                    src="{{ asset($image->location) }}" width="100px"
                                                                    height="100px" alt="image"
                                                                    style="background-position: center background-attachment: fixed;"
                                                                    data-image-id="{{ $image->id }}" name="images">
                                                            </div>
                                                        @endforeach
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="upload_image"
                                                            value="{{ $image->id }}">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To upload multiple, you need to have your `name` attribute be an array in the html element. For example: `name="images[]"` on every image input.

Comment: I want to update multiple images not upload